# I'm getting an excess vertical line in my pandas box plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boxplot

I am using the following code to create a box plot of wave heights in the Pacific Ocean:

```
plt.figure()            
df = pd.DataFrame(wavesPAC,columns=['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC'])
color = dict(boxes='Gray', whiskers='Gray',
                 medians='DarkOrange', caps='Gray')

df.plot.box(color = color,sym='k+')
plt.suptitle("")
plt.ylabel('[Meters]')
plt.title('Pacific Ocean')
plt.show()
```

The data set, wavesPAC, is a 1881*12 numpy array, and some of the columns a couple of NaNs. The plot looks like this:

[image: As you can see, every month]

As you can see, every month except March, May, September and December has a black vertical line through the box. There is no correlation between occurrences of NaNs in the columns and the vertical lines. My only finding is that the sym-argument (where I have specified 'k+') changes the color of the lines. Any ideas?

Comment: what is `wavesPAC`? It's not defined in your snippet

Comment: To create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, chose any candle with the vertical line and start removing data points from it until the line disappears. The last removed point would be the reason for the vertical line.